# SQL performance

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have this SQL statement that works but take a long time to process

I have an a_log table and people table. I need to find the last activity and the associated user for each id for the given person in the people table.

```
SELECT p.`id`, activity, appphone, appname, dateadd 
FROM people p
LEFT JOIN a_log a
ON p.id = a.id 
WHERE (  dateadd >= '2011/09/13 00:00' and dateadd <= '2011/09/13 23:59') 
AND (a.date_time = (SELECT MAX(a1.date_time)
       FROM activity_log a1
       WHERE a.id = a1.id
       GROUP BY id) OR date_time IS NULL)
    ORDER BY `id` desc limit 0, 100
```

I have a non unique index on date_time field and id field in the a_log table
I have a primary index on id field and a non unique index on dateadd field in people table

How can i get a shorter execution time on this query? 
Thank you

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using and what does the execution plan/log show?

Comment: possible duplicate of [tuning a SQL query for better performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405887/tuning-a-sql-query-for-better-performance)

Comment: @ajreal yes i posted that question earlier this all for the same project but mysql is not one of my strong points. thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
SELECT p.`id`, p.activity, p.appphone, p.appname, p.dateadd, a.*
FROM people p
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT a.id, a.date_time, a.user  
    FROM activity_log a 
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT id, MAX(date_time) as date_time
                    FROM activity_log 
                    GROUP BY id
    ) a1  ON a.id = a1.id and a.date_time = a1.date_time
) a ON p.id = a.id 
WHERE (  dateadd >= '2011/09/13 00:00' and dateadd <= '2011/09/13 23:59'   and `agent_or_underwriter` != 'agent') 
ORDER BY p.id desc limit 0, 100
```

Answer (score 2):

At a high high level (without knowing the schema of your tables, your indicies, your RDBMS, your disk structure, etc....).

I would try to remove the subquery either by running 2 queries (one to get the max date and the other to run the outer query).

I would also (as Mark mentioned), look at the execution plan (with mysql use Explain: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain-output.html ), that should put you on the right footing to start optimizing.

If you try these two points you should be able to be in a better position.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a derived table instead of a subquery. Should speed things up significantly.

```
SELECT p.id, activity, appphone, appname, dateadd  
FROM   people p 
       LEFT JOIN a_log a 
       LEFT JOIN (
           SELECT ID, MAX(date_time) MaxDate 
             FROM activity_log
             GROUP BY ID
       ) a1
          ON a.ID = a1.ID
WHERE  a.date_time IS NULL OR a.date_time = ISNULL(a1.MaxDate, a.date_time) --??
ORDER BY id desc limit 0, 100
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a temporary table with an index for the select in your "AND".

Answer (score 0):

*Does this help?  I'm not mysql savvy so the belwo just very well may not be mysql compatable*

```
SELECT p.id, a.activity, a.appphone, a.appname, a.dateadd  

FROM people p LEFT JOIN a_log a ON p.id = a.id  
              LEFT JOIN ( SELECT MAX(a1.date_time)
                          FROM activity_log a1 
                          WHERE a.id = a1.id 
                            AND a1.dateadd >= '2011/09/13 00:00' 
                            and a1.dateadd <= '2011/09/13 23:59'
                          GROUP BY id
                        ) 
                          amax ON a.id = amax.id AND ( a.date_time = amax.date_time or a1.date_time IS NULL )

WHERE 1 = 1 


ORDER BY 'id' desc limit 0, 100
```